# On click bind to form child button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple form and I am trying to apply my custom function it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#async_form").asyncpost(defaultAjaxCallback);

});

$.fn.asyncpost = function(callback)
{

var url = $(this).attr('action');
var btn = $(this).children('input[type=submit]');
var data = $(this).serialize();

$(this).on('click', btn, function(){

    event.preventDefault();
    $.post(url, data, callback);

});

}
```

I want to dynamically get the children.btn of form and detect on click on that. This is working but the problem is that where ever on form i click the click is fired. What am I missing here?

Comment: try by changing `$(this).on('click', btn` to `$(this).on(btn, 'click'`

Answer (score 0):

Check for current target and target property of event.

1. e.currentTarget will return element on which you have clicked.
2. e.target will return element to which the event is attached.

The idea is to check that current target should not be equal to target of event.

Your code will be modified to :-

```
    $.fn.asyncpost = function(callback)
{

var url = $(this).attr('action');
var btn = $(this).children('input[type=submit]');
var data = $(this).serialize();

$(this).on('click', btn, function(e){
    if(e.currentTarget != e.target){
       event.preventDefault();
       $.post(url, data, callback);
    }
});

}
```

You can also do this way :-

```
$(this).on('click', 'input[type=submit]', function(e){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post(url, data, callback);
});
```

```js
var btn = $("#frm").children('input[type=submit]');
$("#frm").on("click",btn,function(e){
  if(e.currentTarget != e.target){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.target);
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="frm">
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem is that [`$.on` takes a string in its `selector` parameter, not a jQuery object](https://api.jquery.com/on/). You'll also need to pass `event` into your click handler, and get the serialized form data in the click handler instead of the ready handler.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#async_form").asyncpost(null);
});

$.fn.asyncpost = function (callback) {
  var url = $(this).attr('action');

  $(this).on('click', 'input[type=submit]', event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    console.log(url, data, callback);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="async_form" action="post.php" method="POST">
  <input name="text">
  <input name="checkbox" type="checkbox">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```